# Kanji identification (low res)

Tags: kanji

I am trying to read the text from a Nintendo DS game, but have encountered a kanji that's (at least for me) difficult to recognise because of the very low resolution of the screen:

[image]

I have tried to narrow it down by parts/radicals, since the right hand side looks like it should be 申, but that didn't seem to get me anywhere and the left side seems even less obvious (at first I thought it might be 有 because of the top left part, but that doesn't seem to be the case either).

Here is the whole sentence where this appears (unknown kanji is marked with ◯):

> ひとり霊前に◯をささげたこのひとの心中を思うと…

Hopefully somebody can see here what I'm missing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is 「榊{さかき}」.

I shall let Wiki explain its meaning and religious use.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleyera_japonica

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. I did actually consider the possibility that the left part was 木 and I even came across the kanji 榊 in the process, but it just didn't seem to fit in my mind and I guess I dismissed the possibility too easily!